# How to force scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, scroll, cancelableoperation

I'm working with Cargo Collective and I have draggable objects across my page.

However that prevents iOS Safari scroll from working properly, since the touchStart event to drag is not cancelable.

Here's the link to the site: https://sarapinto.cargo.site/Denim-Project
The cargo source code affecting this issue can be accessed in `static.cargo/assets/base.js` and `static.cargo/assets/montessouri.js`

I've tried to read the cargo code but it's so dense and I cannot yet fully understand javascript.

How should I proceed? Should I put cancelable= false on the affecting function, but how if I'm working in another script? Or how should I force scroll on iOS?

**This is important**: I cannot directly edit cargo scripts. I can only insert my own script at the header.

Thanks in advance!